# Practical application of Gaussian processes to non-Gaussian data

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, gaussian-process, data-preprocessing

I once saw the following statement on Gaussian processes,

> Gaussian process assumes the target data to be distributed as a multivariate Gaussian, with Gaussian noise.
> This is often an unreasonable assumption to make for the raw data.
> Standard practice is to apply a preprocessing transformation in an ad-hoc manner preceding the modelling with the GP.

I am curious about what do those pre-processing transformation usually involve? In practice, how do we train the Gaussian process when test data does not follow a Gaussian distribution?

Comment: This answer to a similar question might be relevant: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/401066/8298

Answer (score 4):

There are two main ways for handling observations that are not actually Gaussian:

1. Keep using a Gaussian likelihood (noise model), but in a transformed space. I.e., instead of modelling $y = f(x) + \epsilon$ where the noise is normal-distributed, $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$, using $g(y) = f(x) + \epsilon$. Your transform $g(\cdot)$ can be deterministic - a common choice is the log-transform, particularly if your observations $y$ are constrained to be positive. This means you are still doing exact GP regression. You can also learn the transform as in a [Warped Gaussian process](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/zoubin/papers/gpwarp.pdf).
2. Use a more appropriate likelihood, this depends very much on your problem. But the equivalent to the log-transform above would be a Log-Normal likelihood function. Then the GP model is no longer closed-form, and you will have to do some kind of approximation (e.g. MCMC, Expectation Propagation, or variational inference - see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLZ_xn3EIbxZHoq8A3-2F4_rLyy61vkEpU&v=vAM4P3hIyuY&feature=emb_logo)).

Comment: I want to add that for option 1 we are still making the assumption that our random variables are related in a Gaussian copula. And there's a third option: Student-t Processes also have a closed-form solution.