# Under which condition of output, can we use Gaussian process regression?

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis, gaussian-process

I have a simulation tool to calculate output $f$ from input $x$.

And, I'm trying to make a regression model using a Gaussian process from some simulation data, $[x_1, ..., x_n]$ and $[f(x_1), ..., f(x_n)]$.

The goal is to predict $f(x_{n+1})$ for $x_{n+1}$ which is not yet simulated.

I suppose the use of Gaussian process implies that I assume,

> $ [f(x_1), ..., f(x_n), f(x_{n+1})] $ follows a multivariate Gaussian distribution, i.e.,
>
> $ [f(x_1), ..., f(x_n), f(x_{n+1})] \sim \mathcal{N}\Big(\mu([x_1,...,x_n]), K(x, x')\Big) $

How can I show that this assumption is true/valid?

Or, equivalently, under which condition (of $f(x)$), can I use this GP regression?

In addition, I found [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1807.02811) that said

> We first describe GP regression, focusing on $f$'s values at a finite collection of points $x_1, ..., x_k \in \mathbb{R}^d$. It is convenient to collect the function's values at these points together into a vector $[f(x_1), ..., f(x_k)]$. Whenever we have a quantity that is unknown in Bayesian statistics, like this vector, we suppose that it was drawn at random by nature from some prior probability distribution. GP regression takes this prior distribution to be multivariate normal, with a particular mean vector and covariance matrix.

Can we use this GP regression for arbitrary $f(x)$?

Comment: [This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/401066/8298) answer should apply to your question as well.

Comment: From a practical perspective, the important assumption a GP makes is that your function changes smoothly. If it does, is complex, and is of moderate dimension, a GP will be hard to beat.